# How to add Shoelace library of components to existing Stencil.js project

Tags: typescript, import, web-component, stenciljs, shoelace

There is a library called "shoelace" ( https://shoelace.style/getting-started/usage ) which is a collection of web components built with stencil.js. I would like to use the components from that library inside of my existing stencil.js project.

However, when I follow the instructions for a local installation using NPM, it doesn't work, even though the component appears to be loaded.

I receive the following error when I try to render shoelace's button component:
`Class constructor SlButton cannot be invoked without 'new'`

This is my `test-button.tsx` component:

```
import { Component, h} from '@stencil/core';

import '@shoelace-style/shoelace/dist/themes/base.css';

import SlButton from '@shoelace-style/shoelace/dist/components/button/button';


@Component({
  tag: 'test-button',
  shadow: true,
})

export class TestButton {

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <SlButton>hdcsddsy</SlButton>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Shoelace is no longer developed with Stencil. As of beta.29, it uses [Lit](https://lit.dev/). However, the end result is still a collection of custom elements, so you can use them anywhere.

First, install Shoelace:

```
npm i @shoelace-style/shoelace
```

Then, in your Stencil component, import the Shoelace element(s) you want to use like this:

```js
import '@shoelace-style/shoelace/dist/components/button/button';
```

The custom elements are registered via side effect. To use them in your JSX, use the corresponding HTML tag:

```
render() {
  return <sl-button type="primary">Click me!</sl-button>;
}
```

Note: if you're not seeing any styles, you'll also want to [load the light or dark theme](https://shoelace.style/getting-started/installation).